# Usar referencia na condição da query MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Estou fazendo uma query para calcular o saldo e depois de calculado eu quero que ele traga somente os produtos cujo saldo é igual a `0` então tentei atribuir o valor total usando o `AS` só que quando fui fazer a condição no `WHERE` ele não reconheceu

```
SELECT mov.Codigo, (
SUM( IF( (
mov.Tipo =  "2"
), mov.Quantidade, 0 ) ) + SUM( IF( (
mov.Tipo =  "5"
), mov.Quantidade, 0 ) ) + SUM( IF( (
mov.Tipo =  "7"
), mov.Quantidade, 0 ) ) - SUM( IF( (
mov.Tipo =  "3"
OR mov.Tipo =  "4"
OR mov.Tipo =  "6"
), mov.Quantidade, 0 ) ) + ( 
SELECT SUM( quantidade_balanco ) 
FROM balancos
WHERE produto = mov.Codigo )
) AS total
FROM movimentacao AS mov WHERE total=0 
GROUP BY mov.Codigo
```

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'total' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da [documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html):

> Você pode usar alias em cláusulas GROUP BY, ORDER BY, ou HAVING para referenciar a coluna

Ou seja, não é possível usar no `WHERE`. Mas você pode fazer com `HAVING`:

```
SELECT mov.Codigo, (
SUM( IF( (
mov.Tipo =  "2"
), mov.Quantidade, 0 ) ) + SUM( IF( (
mov.Tipo =  "5"
), mov.Quantidade, 0 ) ) + SUM( IF( (
mov.Tipo =  "7"
), mov.Quantidade, 0 ) ) - SUM( IF( (
mov.Tipo =  "3"
OR mov.Tipo =  "4"
OR mov.Tipo =  "6"
), mov.Quantidade, 0 ) ) + ( 
SELECT SUM( quantidade_balanco ) 
FROM balancos
WHERE produto = mov.Codigo )
) AS total
FROM movimentacao AS mov
GROUP BY mov.Codigo
HAVING total=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Já experimentou usar [Having](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) em vez de where?

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo que pode te ajudar é esse aqui:

```
select * from (select emp.codemp from empresa as emp) as cod where cod.codemp = 1;
```

Qualquer duvida só avisar.

Comment: Não é a mesma situação

Comment: realmente não é a mesma situação mas pode ser usado como exemplo pra você usar um alias na clausula where, só usar a imaginação e aplicar no que você quer fazer, não tenho como testar o seu código e lhe dar a resposta agora.

Comment: Sim, concordo... mas como pode ver já sabia dessa possibilidade como no cógido que postei `FROM movimentacao AS mov WHERE total=0 
GROUP BY mov.Codigo` mas obrigado assim mesmo ;)

Comment: Opa blza, tenta usar também o HAVING pode ajudar.